# Strings to Utf-8 Java double quotes "

Tags: java, string, utf-8

I have tried to convert string to utf-8 format in Java

source code used:
`str = new String(str.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");`

Many of encoding issues are solved. But double quotes create an error.

Output is :

> \"Knife\"_Sotelo

Needed Output is:

> %22Knife%22_Sotelo

Comment: You're looking for urlencoded, Not utf8

Comment: `str = new String(str.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8")` is effectively the same as `str = str`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, you are looking for a URL encoding mechanism:

```
String result = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(input, "UTF-8");
```